# How can I override the django AuthenticationForm input css class?

Tags: django, authentication, forms

I have a django site using the basic django registration framework. I have my login page working fine, but I want to change the css class on the inputs. The form passed to the login page looks to be an AuthenticationForm class.

What would be a good way to add a css class to the username, and password fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do what you want like this:

```
def login(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm(request)
    form.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = "custom_css"
    form.fields['password'].widget.attrs['style'] = "background:red"
    return render_to_response("login.html", {'form':form},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What if I am using django.contrib.auth.views.login and I want to include the form on every page in my website? I cannot see the login form I included in base.html and I think it is because I cannot connect the django.contrib.auth.views.login's AuthenticationForm to my CSS file. What do you think?

Comment: 1. you can make a template tag, something like {% get_login_form %}

Comment: 2. you can extend the auth form and overwrite the init method to put the attrs.

Answer (score 13):

Sub class your auth form

### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput

class RFPAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span2','placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'span2','placeholder':'Password'}))
```

Comment: Also try https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks if you just need to add a class.

Comment: The username field in the AuthenticationForm has got [max_langth=254 specified](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L154). Do you think I should add this value to my field too? Are those overwritten by my declaration?