# Django adding placeholders to django built in login forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm using django built-in login [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) and i want to add placeholders to username and password.

My template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ form.username|add_class:'form-control' }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ form.password|add_class:'form-control' }}
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

save this content in `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput


class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}))
```

in your main `urls.py` (where your login view called)

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from app.forms import CustomAuthForm

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login', kwargs={"authentication_form":CustomAuthForm}),
]
```

the extra thing that we done here is added an kwargs `kwargs={"authentication_form":CustomAuthForm}`

please use this for your future reference 
[django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) and [django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm)

Comment: Another way to set up `urls.py` accordingly with ClassBasedViews would be `url(r'^login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=CustomForm), name='login')`

Answer (score 6):

save this content in `forms.py`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput


class MyAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','password']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyAuthForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Username'})
        self.fields['username'].label = False
        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Password'}) 
        self.fields['password'].label = False
```

and save this content in main `urls.py`

```
from users.forms import MyAuthForm

urlpatterns = [
   ...
   path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html', authentication_form=MyAuthForm), name='login'),
   ...
]
```

please refer this site: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py

Answer (score 1):

You can add another filter

```
@register.filter(name="add_place_holder")
def add_place_holder(field, place_holder=None):
    if place_holder == None:
        return field
    else:
        field.field.widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': place_holder})
        return field
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add placeholder something like this,

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModelName
        widgets = {
            'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Username'}),
            'password' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'Password'}),
        }
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: i've seen this somewhere but how do i apply it to the built in form from AuthenticationForm?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment on the other answer. You can subclass the the Authentication form.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput

class PlaceholderAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}))
```

or see the other function that was put in this question. -->
[How can I override the django AuthenticationForm input css class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339369/how-can-i-override-the-django-authenticationform-input-css-class)