# Django Auth add placeholder in the login form

Tags: django, django-forms

I was following this tutorial for Django login:
https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-login-and-logout/

Here is what the code look like to enable login using django auth

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('customers/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),]
```

and created a templates/registration/login.html template

I want to add placeholder string in the login page for username and password.

I tried subclassing the AuthenticationForm (suggested here: [Django adding placeholders to django built in login forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542442/django-adding-placeholders-to-django-built-in-login-forms)) but I am not sure how to make the changes in the urls.py. I do not want to impact the other forms that come with the Django such as auth password_change etc.

Note I am using Django 2.1.5 and python 3.6

**Edit:**

I made the following changes but with no impact:

in customers/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','placeholder': 'Your Username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}))
```

in the urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from customers.forms import CustomAuthForm

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('customers/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), kwargs = {"authentication_form":CustomAuthForm}),
    path('customers/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),]
```

**I am not seeing 'Your Username' and 'Password' string in the login form text area.**

**Fixed Edit**

I changed the urls.py and it worked

```
 path('customers/login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(
template_name='registration/login.html', authentication_form=CustomAuthForm)),
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>In your `project/settings.py` navigate to `TEMPLATES` and set `'DIRS'` to `[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`. This way you tell Django to load it's templates from this folder (if there are any) instead of the virtualenv.</s>

**EDIT:** Try changing `forms.TextInput` to `forms.widgets.TextInput` since it's a class defined in **[django.forms.widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#textinput)**. Do the same for `PasswordInput`.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed you're missing one more thing. Just made an update.

Comment: I edited my post with what you suggested and some modification, am i still missing something?

Comment: If you are able to open the login page without errors at `localhost:8000/customers/login` my guess is that your form fields are not properly defined.

Comment: what do you mean they are not properly defined? Btw, the forms.widgets.TextInput did not work. I am able to actually login to the system. Its  just the UI which is not showing the placeholder text

Comment: I meant that the form is not properly overriding it's fields so there is something in CustomAuthForm that need's to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({
                 'placeholder':'your place holder'})
       # same for the placeholder of passsword.
```

Comment: I tried this with the same urls.py. Still not working!

Comment: by defaults django looks for account/login, also you have to set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  in your setting file to make it work.

Comment: The issue was in the call to 'path';  fixed it with the right argument.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm probably two Years late and you've probably already figured it out, but....

Django already offers a solution for "Anonymous Users" in 'models.py'.

The username property is set to a string of '' '' (username='' ''):

```
    class AnonymousUser:
      id = None
      pk = None
      username = 'user' # GIVE PROPERTY A NAME
      is_staff = False
      is_active = False
      is_superuser = False
      _groups = EmptyManager(Group)
      _user_permissions = EmptyManager(Permission)
```

Once you have that... YOU ARE BASICALLY DONE! Call it in your project's "User Page" ('base.html') under the 'username' property:

```
    {% block welcome-msg %}
      {% translate 'Welcome,' %}
      <strong>{% firstof user.first_name user.username %}</strong> <!-- user.username -->
    {% endblock %}
```