# How can I add placeholder to Django generated input?

Tags: python, django

for login, I am using auth_views.LoginView and I want to add a placeholder to Django generated input, how can I do that?

Comment: Check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542442/django-adding-placeholders-to-django-built-in-login-forms

Comment: its not answering my question

Answer (score 0):

For a Django model you can use a placeholder like

```
from django import forms

from .models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Name'}),
            'description': forms.Textarea(
                             attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter description here'}),
         }
```

is this enough? if not can you specify more things in your question that you need help with.